# Volume of hypersphere brain teaser

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

my physics professor gave us this brain teaser in class for fun, I think i got the answer. Is this correct?

If the earth were a 100-dimensional hypersphere with radius 4000 miles
rather than a three-dimensional sphere of that radius, what fraction of its volume would
be within 40 miles of its surface?

I think the answer is  $1/100^{100}$ I know that the volume of the hypersphere varies directly with r, meaning in 1d its $r^1$, in 2d its $r^2$... etc. and the constants will cancel out since it's a proportion.

so I took $40^{100}/4000^{100}$ = $1/100^{100}$. Is that correct?

Comment: This would have been correct if you would have been $40$ miles from the center. For estimating $40$ miles from the surface, you have to subtract the volume of the sphere of radius $3960$ miles.

Comment: awwwwh, top commentor, you are correct. dang. should've caught that.

Comment: @астон: Perhaps that comment would be better suited as an answer, since you essentially answered the question.

Comment: @MvG You are right, but it is too small to be an answer. I will leave it as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

As [астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/316409/%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%b2%d1%96%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%84-%d0%bc%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%8d%d1%80%d0%b3) already commented, your computation would have been correct if the question were asking about the proportion that is $40$ miles *from the center*. For $40$ miles *from the surface*, $40^{100}$ is not the correct formula, as the hypersphere shell will have larger volume than that. Instead you have to subtract the volume of a hypersphere of radius $3960$ miles from your total hypersphere to get at that shell volume.

$$\frac{4000^{100}-(4000-40)^{100}}{4000^{100}}=
1-\left(1-\frac{40}{4000}\right)^{100}\approx0.634$$

Here you can also see how increasing the dimension will make that proportion increase, since the parenthesis is less than one. For dimension $3$ you only get a result of $0.03$.